# JavaScript opposite of .flat()

Tags: javascript

Is there a JavaScript function that does the opposite of `.flat()`?

I have an array like this:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

That needs to become

```
[[1,2], [3,4], [5]]
```

Is this possible to do automatically, by specifying the wanted size of the arrays (2: `[[1,2], [3,4]]`; 3: `[[1,2,3],[4,5]]`)?

Comment: Typically referred to as grouping or chunking. This is definitely a duplicate question, just need to find it...

Comment: If by "automatically" you meant to ask whether there is a builtin to do that, the answer is no.